# Unable to send commands from Apple Watch to iPhone but commands are going from iPhone to Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchos-2

I'm working on a sample Apple Watch application and trying to send a command from Apple Watch to iPhone.
Getting the following error message.

> 2015-12-21 17:44:17.942 SampleWatch WatchKit Extension[157:4572]
>   requestRecord error: Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7001 "Unknown
>   WatchConnectivity error." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17d51350
>   {Error Domain=com.apple.identityservices.error Code=23 "Timed out"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x17d4a550 {Error
>   Domain=com.apple.ids.idssenderrordomain Code=12 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Timed out}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown
>   WatchConnectivity error.}

Code snippet to send command from Watch to iPhone:

```
    - (void)sendCommand
    {
       NSLog(@" ### SendCommand :%d ###",[self.session isReachable] );
       if ([self.session isReachable]) {
       NSDictionary *message = @{@"Command": @"Hello"};
       [self.session sendMessage:message
                 replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply) {
                     //handle reply from iPhone app here
                     NSLog(@"requestRecord reply: %@", reply);
                 }
                 errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                     //catch any errors here
                     NSLog(@"requestRecord error: %@", error);
                 }
         ];
    }
}
```

Setting up the session as follows:

```
    - (void)setupWatchSession
    {
        if ([WCSession isSupported]) {

        self.session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        self.session.delegate = self;
        [self.session activateSession];

        NSLog(@"@setupWatchSession: %@", self.session);
      }
    }
```

The same way, the set up is done even in the iPhone as well. 
One way (iPhone to Apple Watch) is able to receive the command but the other way from(Apple Watch to iPhone) is resulting in an error.

Comment: Where in the iOS app code do you perform the WCSession's set up (appdelegate, viewcontroller's viewDidLoad, etc)?

Comment: Similar methods are also written in AppDelegate to set up the WCSession in iOS.

Comment: Usually I've  I've seen this error when the iOS app didn't activate its WCSession, which is why I asked. Could you post the implementation of the didReceiveMessage on the iOS side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to comment yet, so...
You might want to replace `self.session` with `[WCSession defaultSession]` when you call `sendMessage`. Sometimes ARC will dealloc that var for whatever reason.

This is my code and it works for me:

```
 [[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:@{@"file":urlOut.absoluteString, @"langFrom":langFrom,@"langTo":langTo, @"data":dataFromFile } replyHandler:^(NSDictionary * _Nonnull replyMessage) {
                NSLog(@"%@",replyMessage);

                [[HistoryDemon summon] addItem:replyMessage];

                [self presentControllerWithName:@"TranslationTableView" context:nil];

            } errorHandler:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",error);
            }];
```

!Note I still use watchOS 2.0 //to scared to update to 2.1 :D

One more thing, starting with watchOS 2.0 the `[WCSession isSupported]` is always `YES`, so you can skip that on the watch.

Let me know if it helped, I'll keep updating my answer, if not.

Comment: Still I face the same issue. My device has been updated to 2.1. In 2.0, app used to get stuck in the splash screen itself. Now the app is getting installed properly in 2.1 but getting the error while sending commands.

Comment: tried moving the entire code from InterfaceController class to ExtensionDelegate, but still the same issue.

Comment: Hmmm, ok have you tried this:
`[self.session updateApplicationContext:applicationDict error:nil];` to send and to catch it use `- (void)session:(WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)message;`

Comment: Tried  using [self.session updateApplicationContext:applicationDict error:&outError]; to send. There is no error but I didn't receive any call to session:didReceiveMessage:

Comment: Is there anything that I need to check in Watch settings? Anything related to resetting the device or restarting Watch or anything related to bluetooth? Because I could see a similar error message in another application which I had.

Comment: you could always, "unpair" the devices and restart the phone and watch, then pair again "as new device", sometimes this helps

Comment: Hey dude, Thanks a lot. It worked. Unpairing and pairing it again as a new device has worked :) :) :)

Comment: I had the same issue. Restart iphone and Apple watch!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bug in watch OS 2 https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19213